# What are good ways to build dynamic tabs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, plugins, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to build a page with dynamic tabs where if a user clicks on one tab, they are shown the content of that tab.  Once they click another tab, the content of the new tab is displayed without refreshing the page.

I know there are a few options out there to use, mainly:

JQuery UI
Tabulous
TabsOnRails

I am not sure which one people have used and which one is "better" both in terms of ease of use/understanding as well as performance.  Let me know what you guys think.

Also, since JQuery UI has a lot of other functions like draggable, etc. Is there a way I can install just the tabs portion of JQuery UI using homebrew?

Thanks a lot in advance.

***EDIT***

Let me clarify, this is for a product site so the tabs are the description and reviews for each individual product.  Each product page will have those tabs and the content of each of the tabs changes with different products.

Comment: I was just looking at tabulous and wondering the same thing. I already use JQuery tabs and found it annoying to manage which tab is selected (in the controller, I set "@tab = 'appropriate_string'", then in the view for the tabs (a partial), check what value "@tab" has to see which tab to give focus.  I think that's an indication I should be using tabulous because I'm retrofitting load-new-page behavior into what's supposed to be an all-one-page widget.  Would love to see more discussion on this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the content is not a lot, then just show all of them as the page loads, and use jQuery to do the magic.
2. If the content is a lot, using Ajax or render a new page (with similar tab but different highlited tab) can be useful. I recommend rendering a new page for SEO sake.
3. I don't know why homebrew comes into picture in this. You can simply follow the examples in jQuery UI, and learn from it. Draggable is something difficult to learn though.

**EDIT**
Upon asker updates, I would suggest running it as a separate render. For example, in the product URL: http://abc.com/products/1234, then for the tab for reviews: http://abc.com/products/1234/reviews. Just make a new controller for `reviews` will do.

Comment: Thanks for responding Victor, please see the edit to the question.  As for homebrew, I want to use it to install the plugins - assuming I want to add TabsOnRails or something

Comment: Homebrew still doesn't come in to it, they're gems/plugins. brew is for things like native apps that need compilation.

Comment: ah. Thanks.  Do you have a suggestion for how I can build these tabs?  Thanks.